# Как получить данные при парсинге Госуслуг?

Tags: python, парсер, requests

Делаю программу для чтения qr о вакцинации и проверки его на действительность.
Получаю ссылку на страницу с сертификатом и забираю оттуда элемент по id.
Если переходить напрямую и смотреть элементы вручную, то все ок, все отображается. Но, если я делаю запрос requests, то нужное мне поле оказывается пустым.

И тут вопрос: я делаю что-то не так или госуслуги не дают мне парсить их?

код:

```
from PIL import Image
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result = decode(Image.open('qr.PNG'))
link1 = str(result[0][0]).replace("b'", "")
link = link1.replace("'", "")
r = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
print(soup.find('span', id='status'))
```

print дает такую картину:

```
<span class="status-value cert-name" id="status"></span>
```

если смотреть на сайте, то вот так:

```
<span id="status" class="status-value cert-name">Действителен</span>
```

Comment: Это значит что DOM меняется динамически и request для такой задачи не подходит. я бы посоветовал использовать selenium webdriver, который может эмулировать реальное открытие страницы и подождать пока загрузятся все элементы html

Comment: ... и отработает JavaScript, который загружает информацию.

Comment: @skuch, убедитесь что пользовательское соглашение Госуслуг разрешает разбирать страницы скриптами. Там может быть специальный пункт, что вы можете только смотреть глазами (живыми :).